# Two permutations of $S_n$ are conjugate if and only if they have the same cycle structure: Looking for a proof based on actions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

The cycle structure of a permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ pops up naturally if we consider the action of $\langle \sigma \rangle$ as a group of permutations on the set $I_n:=\{1,\dots,n\}$ ("natural action"). By the Orbit-Stabilizer Theroem (O.S.T.), we get:

$$|O_\sigma(j)||\operatorname{Stab}_\sigma(j)|=o(\sigma), \forall j\in I_n \tag 1$$

where:

$$\operatorname{Stab}_\sigma(j):=\{\sigma^k\mid \sigma^k(j)=j\} \le \langle\sigma\rangle, \forall j\in I_n \tag 2$$

Now, given $\alpha \in S_n$, it is $(\alpha\sigma\alpha^{-1})^k=\alpha\sigma^k\alpha^{-1}$ (induction on $k$), so we get:

\begin{alignat}{1}
\operatorname{Stab}_{\alpha\sigma\alpha^{-1}}(j)&=\{\alpha\sigma^k\alpha^{-1}\mid (\alpha\sigma^k\alpha^{-1})(j)=j\} \\
&=\{\alpha\sigma^k\alpha^{-1}\mid \alpha(\sigma^k(\alpha^{-1}(j)))=j\} \\
&=\{\alpha\sigma^k\alpha^{-1}\mid \sigma^k(\alpha^{-1}(j))=\alpha^{-1}(j)\} \\
&=\{\alpha\sigma^k\alpha^{-1}\mid \sigma^k \in \operatorname{Stab}_\sigma(\alpha^{-1}(j))\} \\
&=\alpha \operatorname{Stab}_\sigma(\alpha^{-1}(j)) \alpha^{-1}, \forall \alpha \in S_n,\forall j\in I_n\\
\tag 3
\end{alignat}

whence:

$$|\operatorname{Stab}_{\alpha\sigma\alpha^{-1}}(j)|=|\operatorname{Stab}_\sigma(\alpha^{-1}(j))|, \forall \alpha \in S_n,\forall j\in I_n \tag 4$$

But since $\forall \alpha \in S_n, o(\alpha\sigma\alpha^{-1})=o(\sigma)$, $(4)$ implies (again by the O.S.T.):

> $$|O_\sigma(\alpha^{-1}(j))|=|O_{\alpha\sigma\alpha^{-1}}(j)|, \forall \alpha \in S_n, \forall j\in I_n
> \tag 5$$

Therefore, for every $\alpha \in S_n$, the orbits induced by $\langle \alpha\sigma\alpha^{-1}\rangle$ and $\langle \sigma\rangle$ are pairwise of equal size. Moreover, if we denote by $\mathcal{O}$ the set of orbits, we have:

> \begin{alignat}{1}
> |\mathcal{O}_{\alpha\sigma\alpha^{-1}}| &= \frac{1}{o(\alpha\sigma\alpha^{-1})}\sum_{j=1}^{n}|\operatorname{Stab}_{\alpha\sigma\alpha^{-1}}(j)| \\
> &=\frac{1}{o(\sigma)}\sum_{j=1}^{n}|\operatorname{Stab}_\sigma(\alpha^{-1}(j))| \\
> &=\frac{1}{o(\sigma)}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\operatorname{Stab}_\sigma(i)| \\
> &=|\mathcal{O}_\sigma| \\
> \tag 6
> \end{alignat}

So, for every $\alpha \in S_n$, the natural actions of $\langle\sigma\rangle$ and $\langle\alpha\sigma\alpha^{-1}\rangle$ induce the same number of orbits of the same size in pairs, namely $\sigma$ and $\alpha\sigma\alpha^{-1}$ have the same cycle structure.

I would like to prove *within this framework* the converse implication (if two permutations have the same cycle structure, then they are conjugate), but I'm finding it harder. Could you give me some hint, please?

Comment: The $\alpha$ in the conjugation $\alpha\sigma\alpha^{-1}$ can be thought of as a relabelling of the set. So, $\{i_1,\ldots,i_r\}$ is an orbit for $\sigma$ if and only if $\{\alpha(i_1),\ldots,\alpha(i_r)\}$ is an orbit for $\alpha\sigma\alpha^{-1}$.

Comment: Cf. Michael Artin, *Algebra*, Chapter 7. He gave a pretty easily understandable way to prove and explain this: relabeling indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

1) It is enough to show that two cycles of the same length are conjugate.

2) Use the formula: $\enspace\sigma\, (a_{i_1}\,\dots\,a_{i_k})\,\sigma^{-1}=(a_{\sigma (i_1)}\,\dots\,a_{\sigma (i_k)})$.